# How to create multiple arrays from one array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, logic

I have an array "values1" that has 104 items total, i need to create 1 array of 13 sub arrays and each sub array should have 8 values.

e.g if "values1" has item:

```
1,2,3,4,5 ..., 13,
14,15,15,... , 26,
27,28,29,...
```

and i need sub Arrays like this:

```
first subarray: 1,14,27, ....
second subarray: 2,15,18,...
```

and this is how i need to create 13 subArrays in one single array.

```
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                               pathForResource: @"values" ofType: @"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *values1 = [strFileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"@@"];
```

Comment: so you are not taking first 8 values for a separate array ? you need every 8th element into a separate array ?

Comment: @Mr.T yes, but i need every 13th value in one array

Comment: do the math, work on the loop conditions. for the first iteration index is 0, load every 13th element, second iteration start from index 1, and load every 13th element...

Comment: @Mr.T ahan... yeah i am actually trying to get the easy and logical way to do it.. other wise it not very hard...

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks mate, your answer did help a lot... you can see my answer blow.

Comment: as along as it works for you, never mind about the downvotes. NExt time show your effort while asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"values" ofType: @"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *values1 = [strFileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"@@"];
NSMutableArray *graph1Values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int a=0; a<13; a++) {
NSMutableArray *newarray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=a; i<values1.count; i=i+13){
    [newarray1 addObject:[values1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
    [graph1Values addObject:newarray1];
}

NSLog(@"%@",graph1Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tiny category for this:

NSArray+Split.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (Split)

-(NSArray *) splitIntoSubarrays:(NSInteger) count;

@end
```

NSArray+Split.m

```
#import "NSArray+Split.h"

@implementation NSArray (Split)

-(NSArray *) splitIntoSubarrays:(NSInteger) count 
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.count; i++)
    {
        if (i < count)
        {
            arrayOfArrays[i] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [arrayOfArrays[i % count] addObject:self[i]];
    }
    return arrayOfArrays;
}

@end
```

usage:

```
#import "NSArray+Split.h"

(...)

    NSArray *arrayOfArrays = [initialArray splitIntoSubarrays:13];
```